# email_auth pakcage flutter is not working in Test mode

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

email_auth was working fine in test mode

A few months ago. But now it has started giving me error "
unable to access server
end package error"
this is my code

Actually, it is my final year project app and viva is going to be held on 22 Nov. 2022.
I opened this project after 3 months, and everything is fine and working as expected, but the email_auth package is giving an error. I am using this in test mode. Because I am a beginner.

```
import 'package:expense_manager_application/pages/signup_page.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:email_auth/email_auth.dart';


bool _result = false;

class OtpPage extends StatefulWidget {

OtpPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override

State<OtpPage> createState() => _OtpPageState();

}

class _OtpPageState extends State<OtpPage> {

final _emailController = TextEditingController();

final _otpController = TextEditingController();

EmailAuth emailAuth = EmailAuth(sessionName: "OTP for Expense App");

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(

  backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,

  body: Center(

    child: Container(

      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),

      child: Column(

        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

        children: [

          TextField(

            controller: _emailController,

            decoration: InputDecoration(

                hintText: 'Email to verify', icon: Icon(Icons.email)),

          ),

          const SizedBox(

            height: 30,

          ),

          TextField(

            controller: _otpController,

            decoration: InputDecoration(

              hintText: 'Enter otp Here',


              icon: Icon(Icons.message_outlined),

            ),

          ),

          const SizedBox(

            height: 30,

          ),

          Row(

            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,

            children: [

              ElevatedButton(

                onPressed: () {

                  sendOtp();

                },

                child: Text('Send Otp'),

              ),

              ElevatedButton(

                onPressed: () {

                  verifyOtp();

                  if (_result == true) {

                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(

                        builder: (context) => SignupPage()));

                  }

                },

                child: Text('Verify otp'),

              ),

            ],

            )

            ],

      ),

    ),

  ),

 );

 }

 void sendOtp() async {

 print(_emailController.value.text);

 bool status = await emailAuth.sendOtp(

  recipientMail: _emailController.value.text.trim(),

 );

 if (status) {

  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(

    const SnackBar(

      content: Text('Otp Sent'),

    ),

  );

  }

  }

void verifyOtp() async {

_result = await emailAuth.validateOtp(

    recipientMail: _emailController.value.text,

    userOtp: _otpController.value.text);

if (_result) {

  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(

    const SnackBar(

      content: Text('Otp verified'),

    ),

  );

 }

}


}
```

Here is the debug console output.

```
I/flutter ( 2414): mc210200011@vu.edu.pk
V/AudioManager( 2414): querySoundEffectsEnabled...
I/flutter ( 2414): email-auth >> Remote server is not available -- using test server --
I/flutter ( 2414): email-auth >> ❗ Warning this is not reliable on production
I/flutter ( 2414): --- Package Error ---
I/flutter ( 2414): Unable to access server. 
I/flutter ( 2414): --- End Package Error ---
```

I tried reinstalling this package.
My test firestore expired I updated the rules, and everything is working fine except this email_auth otp.

Comment: try updating the ``email_auth`` version to the latest available version in the ``pubspec.yaml`` file.

Comment: I tried this but still the same issue

Comment: Hi, As of now test servers are obsolete, So no more test servers, I did have a poll also regarding the same. A newer version of email_auth will include a better support for production servers. Kindly expect a delay